# How do I say that an infinite-state Markov chain is positive recurrent?

Tags: recurrence-relations, markov-chains

I run into this Markov chain while I'm doing my research, and I can't figure out how to find the condition under which this Markov chain is positive recurrent.

This is a brief scenario of my research:

There is a buffer. This buffer can keep 'unresolved symbols', and they are taken away from the buffer when they are resolved.

At any discrete time instant,

With probability $p^2$, X number of unresolved symbols are saved in the buffer.

With probability $2p(1-p)$, Y number of unresolved symbols in the buffer are resolved. In other words, they are taken away from the buffer.

With probability $(1-p)^2$, Z number of unresolved symbols in the buffer are resolved.

If Y, Z are greater than the number of unresolved symbols in the buffer at a given time, all the unresolved symbols are taken away from the buffer.

So, here I have a specific example: X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 3.

In the Markov chain that I have for this example, the transition probabilities are as follows:

For i = 0, 1, ...

From state i to state i+1: $p^2$

For i = 2, 3, ...

From state i to state i-1: $2p(1−p)$

For i = 3, 4, ...

From state i to state i-3: $(1−p)^2$

Other than these transition probabilities,

From state 1 to 0: $2p(1-p) + (1-p)^2$

From state 2 to 0: $(1−p)^2$

All other transition probabilities : self-transitions.

There transition probabilities will be different depending on the values of X, Y, and Z.

I'd like to come up with an easy way to prove if a given infinite-state Markov chain is positive recurrent or not. I know that there is a theorem saying that if there is a solution to the following, the Markov chain is positive recurrent, and vice versa:

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \pi_{i} = 1$

$\pi_i = \sum_{j} \pi_j p_{ij}$

where $\pi_i$ is the probability of state $i$, $p_{ij}$ is the transition probability from state $j$ to $i$.

But finding a solution every time I have an infinite-state Markov chain doesn't seem to be a good idea to me in that I have variables X, Y, and Z.

So if there is a way to easily check if a given Markov chain is positive recurrent, it will be extremely handy.

Thanks!

P.S.
Sorry that I've been very unclear in asking this question. I've learned a lot since I posted this. Even I wouldn't understand my question if I read this question without knowing what's really behind it. Thanks all. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Please check your formula. If the series $\pi_i$ is convergent, then this is also the case for any linear combination of $\pi_i, \pi_{i+1},...$, hence by your formula the constant series equal to $(1-p)^2$ is convergent, a contradiction (if $p\not =1$).

Comment: What are the transition probabilities of the underlying Markov chain? It seems only transitions from $i$ to $j\leqslant i$ have positive probability... then the whole question becomes rather absurd.

Comment: It seems I need to elaborate my question a bit more.

For i = 0, 1, ...
From state i to state i+1: $p^2$

For i = 1, 2, ...
From state i to state i-1: $2p(1-p)$

For i = 3, 4, ...
From state i to state i-3: $(1-p)^2$

Other than these transition probabilities,
From state 1 to 0, 2 to 0: $(1-p)^2$

All other transition probabilities : self-transitions.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. You could have skipped mine, but you didn't. Thanks for your patience, and kindness to help me out.

Comment: @Did Did I make mistakes in my question? Transitions from $i$ to $j > i$ are positive if I draw the Markov chain.

Comment: @Kelenner I doubled checked it, and it still makes sense to me. Even though I can't express the condition of p which makes this whole Markov chain positive recurrent, I see that if p is very small, the probability of staying at state 0 will be large, and it will be coming back to state 0 an infinite number of times.

Comment: @PurplePenguin Well, perhaps I do not understand clearly what is your question. For me, $p$ is fixed. (And I suppose $p\not =1$). The series $\sum \pi_i$ is convergent (hence the $\pi_i$ are for $i\geq 1$ real numbers.) Let $S_k\in \mathbb{R}$ the sum of the series $\sum_{i\geq 1}\pi_{i+k}$, for $k=0,1,2,3$. By your recurrence formula, we have
$$p^2\pi_i-2p(1-p)\pi_{i+1}-(1-p)^2\pi_{i+2}-(1-p)^2\pi_{i+3}=(1-p)^2$$
Hence the series $\sum(1-p)^2$ is convergent, with sum $p^2S_0-2p(1-p)S_1-(1-p)^2S_2-(1-p)^2S_3\in \mathbb{R}$.But 
$\sum(1-p)^2=+\infty$.

Comment: "Transitions from i to j>i are positive if I draw the Markov chain." Perhaps they are but WE CANNOT SAY until you indicate what the transition probabilities are. (Note that @Kelenner's objection and mine are different but that both need to be addressed seriously before we see a real question here.)

Comment: @Kelenner Oh, I found out what confuses you. My recurrence formula should be the following:

$p^2\pi_i - \{2p(1-p) + (1-p)^2\}\pi_{i+1} - (1-p)^2\pi_{i+2} - (1-p)^2\pi_{i+3} = 0$

Not,


$p^2\pi_i−2p(1−p)\pi_{i+1}−(1−p)^2\pi_{i+2}−(1−p)^2\pi_{i+3}=(1−p)^2$

I assume you missed the braces.

Comment: @Did I see your point. I should've posted a question that has a lot more info such as, in what context this question arises, why I have such equations, etc.


Here it is:

There is a buffer, which can reserve 'unresolved symbols.' These symbols will be taken care of later, and disappear from the buffer.

Indices of states indicate the number of unresolved symbols in the buffer.

At any given state, with probability $p^2$, 1 unresolved symbol will be added to the buffer.

At any given state, with probability $2p(1-p)$, 1 unresolved symbol will be removed from the buffer.

Comment: @Did At any given state, with probability $(1-p)^2$, 3 unresolved symbols will be removed from the buffer.

This is why if we draw the Markov chain, there are transitions from state 2 to 0, 1 to 0 with probability $(1-p)^2$. When there are only 1 or 2 unresolved symbols, with probability $(1-p)^2$, those symbols will be removed, since at most 3 unresolved symbols can be resolved with probability $(1-p)^2$.

Comment: @Did 
Actually, I have to generalize this situation to the case where X unresolved symbols are added to the buffer w.p. $p^2$, Y symbols can be removed from the buffer w.p. $(1-p)^2$, etc.

I should get to that point after I solve this simple situation where numbers X, Y are explicitly given.

Comment: "Even I wouldn't understand my question if I read this question without knowing what's really behind it." This made my day... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For i = 0, 1, ... From state i to state i+1: $p^2$  For i = 1, 2, ... From state i to state i-1: $2p(1-p)$  For i = 3, 4, ... From state i to state i-3: $(1-p)^2$  Other than these transition probabilities, From state 1 to 0, 2 to 0: $(1-p)^2$  All other transition probabilities : self-transitions.

A stationary distribution $(\pi_i)$, if it exists, must be such, at least for $i\geqslant3$, $$\pi_i=p^2\pi_{i-1}+2p(1-p)\pi_{i+1}+(1-p)^2\pi_{i+3}.$$ These are not the identities in your post.

If the question is to solve the identities every stationary distribution must satisfy, I suggest to start from the correct ones above, to add the ones corresponding to "small" values of $i$, and to proceed.

If the question is to determine when the Markov chain is positive recurrent, note that the drift of the chain at every $i\geqslant3$ is $$1\cdot p^2+(-1)\cdot2p(1-p)+(-3)\cdot(1-p)^2=4p-3.$$ Thus, the Markov chain is positive recurrent if $p\lt\frac34$ and transient if $p\gt\frac34$.

Comment: Hi Did,

Thanks a lot. You've been extremely helpful in solving this problem. I just edited my question above. As I was doing that, realized that I was really unclear in asking the question. Sorry about that.

Your second comment (if my question is to determine when the Markov chain...) is exactly what I'd like to know.

Is it sufficient to show that the so-called 'drift' is negative? Is the drift being negative the if-and-only-if condition to the Markov chain being positive-recurrent?

Comment: If the probability transitions of the chain $(X_n)$ are stationary far enough from the origin, that is, if the probability of $i\to j$ depends only on $j-i$ for $i$ large enough, then one can compare $(X_n)$ to a sum $Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$ of i.i.d. random variables $(Y_n)$ distributed like the displacements of $(X_n)$ hence yes, the law of large numbers shows the transience of $(X_n)$ when $E(Y_1)\gt0$. The same argument plus some large deviations estimate (or some other argument I am missing at the moment) show positive recurrence when $E(Y_1)\lt0$.

Comment: And I am pretty sure $(X_n)$ cannot be positive recurrent when $E(Y_1)=0$... but I would have to think more about this case to solve it completely (hence the modification of the conclusion of my answer).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know by any chance where I could get some detailed expository work on your argument above? That showing $E(Y_n)<0$ is a mathematical safe and easy way to show positive recurrence?

Comment: Cause not only do I have to solve this particular problem, but also I should know this stuff to be good at this. Probability and random processes are everywhere.

Comment: You might do worse than to study [these lecture notes](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/312/RW.pdf) (note the paragraph dealing with "skip-free" random walks). Where, by the way, you will find a solution of the case $E(Y_1)=0$ I was too lazy to complete. Then the bibliography [at the same place](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/312/index.html).